# Thymeleaf string substitution and escaping

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a string which contains raw data, which I want escaped. The string also contains markers which I want to replace with span tags.

For example my string is

*"blah  {0}something to span{1} < random chars <"*

I would like the above to be rendered within a div, and replace {0} with  and {1} with

I have tried a number of things, including doing the substitution in my controller, and trying to use the **th:utext** attribute, however I then get SAX exceptions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It looks using message parameters is the right approach to output formatted strings.  See http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#messages

I suspect you need to pass character entity reference in order to avoid SAX exceptions

```
<span th:utext = "#{string.pattern(${'&lt;span&gt;john&lt;/span&gt;'}, ${'&lt;span&gt;doe&lt;/span&gt;'})}"/>
```

Alternatively place the markup in your .properties file:

```
string.pattern=my name is <span>{0}</span> <span>{1}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using i18n ?

something like:

resource.properties:

```
string.pattern=my name is {0} {1}
```

thymeleaf view:

```
<label th:text="#{__${#string.pattern('john', 'doe')}__}"></label>
```

The result should be:

```
my name is john doe
```

Im not sure this  is a good way. But I hope it could help you